# Can I pass a variable to an internally defined function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a script I found online: http://fabricjs.com/particles/

And I'm having an issue where I want to define the number of particles to show outside that script as it changes.

The line:

```
var total = 1000
```

will need to change from time to time.

I tried adding it to my classes but ended up with all sorts of errors that I spent hours trying to figure out, but ended up giving up on that. So, I've decided to use this original script and just try and change the number from the outside when I need to.

Can I pass in a variable somehow?

Edit: Here's a JSBin example of what I would like to do: http://jsbin.com/fasozewovi/1/edit?js

Not sure if something like that is possible though.

Comment: please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do. Is there some way to do this? http://jsbin.com/fasozewovi/1/edit?js

Answer (score 1):

In javascript if you initialize a variable in a function using var, this will be private var. But if you delete initialization lines, it should work.
So the solution is: Check the original code you have to delete all

```
var total=/*something*/
```

Yes, this is this easy. I don't have time to check the code, but are you sure there's not a variable that you can modify because it's defined by the original code?

Comment: Such a simple thing! Apparently I need to learn more about scope in JS. That was perfect. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me.